# c++ class using a lambda in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Using c++11
I want to create a class that uses a lambda as part of a calculation.

```
//contrived sample of potential usage
void random_class::some_function(void)
{
 auto an_object = new my_custom_object(5, [this](){ return random_class_member * 5; });
 an_object.do_some_processing();
 random_class_member++;
 an_object.do_some_processing();
}
```

I am not quite sure how to go about declaring and defining my_custom_object.

```
class my_custom_object
{
public:
 template <typename Proc>
 my_custom_object(int a, Proc p)
 {
  privatea = a;
  privatep = p;
 }
 void do_some_processing()
 {
  privatea += privatep();
 }
private:
 int privatea;
 Proc privatep;
}
```

*unknown type name 'Proc'*

Comment: There is no relation between them

Comment: You may want to look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for storing the lambda.

Comment: You need to `template` the entire class, not just the constructor

Comment: How would I use my_custom_object with a lambda if the entire class is templated? What would random_class::some_function look like?

Comment: why `privatea = a`? Why not `this.a = a`? Or `my_custom_object(int a, std::function<int(void)> p) : a(a), p(p) {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take.

### Use a type-erased `std::function`

For example:

```
class my_custom_object {
public:
    my_custom_object(int a, std::function<void()> p)
    {
        privatea = a;
        privatep = p;
    }
    void do_some_processing()
    {
        privatea += privatep();
    }

private:
    int privatea;
    std::function<void()> privatep;
};
```

This allows `my_custom_object` to accept *any* function-like thing that accepts no parameters.  There is some performance overhead though, since the calls to `privatep` have to be resolved at runtime.  This is likely negligible, but it could matter if this is happening in a tight loop in a performance-critical section of your program though.

The call site would look exactly as you have it now:

```
void random_class::some_function(void)
{
   my_custom_object an_object{5, [this](){ return random_class_member * 5; }};
   an_object.do_some_processing();
   random_class_member++;
   an_object.do_some_processing();
}
```

### Template `my_custom_object` on the type of function it holds.

For example:

```
template <typename Proc>
class my_custom_object {
public:
    my_custom_object(int a, Proc p)
    {
        privatea = a;
        privatep = p;
    }
    void do_some_processing()
    {
        privatea += privatep();
    }

private:
    int privatea;
    Proc privatep;
};
```

This will allow your calls to `privatep` to be resolved statically at compile time, which may have slightly better performance than using `std::function`.  This does mean that the type of `Proc` is now part of the type of `my_custom_object` though, so it's a bit less flexible in some situations.

Since C++17 added class template argument deduction, the call site would look exactly the same:

```
void random_class::some_function(void)
{
   my_custom_object an_object{5, [this](){ return random_class_member * 5; }};
   an_object.do_some_processing();
   random_class_member++;
   an_object.do_some_processing();
}
```

If you have to use a pre-C++17 compiler you'll have to specify the template parameter to `my_custom_object` explicitly:

```
void random_class::some_function(void)
{
   auto func = [this](){ return random_class_member * 5; };
   my_custom_object<decltype(func)> an_object{5, func};
   an_object.do_some_processing();
   random_class_member++;
   an_object.do_some_processing();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the signature of the lambda is fixed you can remove the template and use `std::function<ReturnType(parameters)>`. In your case

```
using Proc = std::function<int(void)>;
```

should work. Then you can pass a lambda that takes no arguments and returns an int.